# Why are there so many unused tags

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I had a look at the most popular tags and I noticed that the last 80 or so pages of tags had never been used.

I was just wondering why there are so many unused tags, for example: [zc.buildout](/questions/tagged/zc.buildout).

Comment: I guess you're looking at the synonyms? Click on one of them and see it take you to another tag.

Comment: no this page http://stackoverflow.com/tags?page=1&tab=popular if you go to the end 80 pages there are unused tags

Comment: Most of those are tag synonyms. Like I said, click on them and you'll be taken to a tag wiki with actual questions. Those that have no questions might have been cleaned up today and will disappear within 24 hours.

Comment: Though some of them arent

Comment: [tag:zc.buildout] is currently *suggested* as a synonym of the tag [tag:buildout]. So it does exist in the system, it just has no questions under it.

Comment: I love the fact that we have [zombies](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/zombie-process/synonyms) on SO

Comment: I know and [tag:zombie]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because people pick bad tags, either because they don't know better, or by accident (there are hundreds of new tags each day that are misspellings of other real tags).  They generally get fixed quickly enough through edits, but the tags themselves die with the daily tag removal script that runs every day. Some are also synonyms.

Comment: They take 24 hours to purge, if no questions are tagged with them.